# scikit learn logistic regression to annotate single cell RNA seq data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to use scikit learn logistic regression to train a model on a labelled single cell RNA sample and subsequently apply this model on new unlabelled single cell RNA seq samples to annotate the cells in these samples. The sample I use to train the model has about 23000 genes but the unlabelled samples have a different number of genes. The trained model expects an input of 23000 genes so I want to ask what the best approach would be.

I could alter the count table of each of the unlabelled samples and add the missing genes with value 0 for all cells and use this to fit the model on. But this would introduce false information.

I could take the intersection of all genes for all samples and train the model on this set of common genes. But then the model depends a lot on the specific samples that are being analysed.

So none of these options seem correct to me.

I have successfully trained the model on the labelled data and I am now struggling to find the right strategy to proceed.

I would very much appreciate any input!

This is what I did:

d23_counts_norm is the normalised counts table I used to train and test the model.

d23_norm.obs["CellType"] refers to the cell type annotation in this sample. I want to train a model so it can distinguish the different cell types present in the annotated model using the gene expression data.

The cells are split: 80% for training, 20% for testing.

The model scores are good: 0,99 and 0,94 when training and testing the model.

When I want to apply the model on a new sample (LX146_norm count table) the error tells me the model expects 23656 features (because the sample the model was trained on had this many features) but finds only 19389 features in the new sample.

[image: scikit learn steps]
[image: The scores on the train and test data are good]
[image: Error when trying to fit model on new sample]
[image: Different nr of features in new sample compared to sample the model was trained on]

Comment: I need some help with understanding your task: you got one RNA seq and predict one cell type for this entire seq. Did I get that correctly? Then you have one training sample and one test sample.

Comment: I have scRNA seq data of an organoid sample of which the cell types have been annotated. So I indeed have one sample on which I trained the model. This model I want to use to identify/annotate the cell types in other organoid samples for which I have scRNA seq data. To keep it simple I first wanted to use the model on one test sample, but I have in fact several test samples. Hope this is clear!

Comment: Thanks, that brings some clarity. However, I still don't understand your data, could you maybe edit your question to contain a short example sequence or something like that?

Comment: Hi, I edited my comment!

Comment: Thanks. If the features are counts of something, I don't see a problem with inserting 0 (or the normalised equivalent, respectively) for the missing features in the second sample. Of course it would be good if you could test this with another labelled sample...